# CSS Style parent based on child selector

Tags: css

i would like to know how to write a selector for this case:

```
<a href="/shows/test/..." class="ico-wrap">
  <img titie="something" width="91" src="somthing.jpg" />
  <span class="ico">
   <i class="ss-play">content</i>
  </span>
</a>
```

I am trying to style all images that have a size of 91 that also contain a span with class .ico that has an "i" tag of ss-play. pretty much i was to style the ico span if it has children "i" with class ss-play

My first attempt was to solve this with the url, so i used this selector, which works fine however, there are instances in the html where the style is overridden.

```
a.ico-wrap[href*="shows"] img[width*="91"] ~ .ico
```

this style selected all a tags with ico-wrap class that had images of that width. though it worked,  i quickly noticed not all images with "shows" in their links had a play icon. so the solution was partial. i want to be able to target those images(91) that somehow have that i tag with ss-play. Please help.

Comment: From what I understand, this is intentionally not possible

Comment: There are so many posts about styling parent elements based on children. It can't be done with just CSS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only possibility is to place the image inside the `.ico` tag.
Otherwise it will not work with pure CSS due to the function of CSS. It is cascading and you cannot select a specific element, which contains a specific element.